# Child is calculating 100% width from screen, not parent

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fit a progress bar into the parent, which is oddly difficult. It is done on a Jot form, but with access to custom CSS and so on, which I have utilized a lot (**that could have created the problem I guess**).

The progress bar is positioned fixed at the top, and is in the parent element div.form-all as the very first and second element. I have tried all the common suggestions on here about box-sizing and so on, but nothing seems to work.

My suspicion is that it is because the parent element does not have an explicitly stated width, as this fixes the problem monumentally (but breaks the responsiveness, as it goes from ≈36% width to 100% on small screens).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The actual form can be found here, at Jot form, in Danish:

All added custom CSS should be visible by inspecting the elements, but I will mention that it has worked before.

The div containing the progress div has the following css-attributes:
    .progressBarContainer.fixed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: inherit;
    background: #FFF;
    z-index: 9999;}

The parent has by Jotform-coding the following relevant attributes, with no position attribute:
    .form-all {
    width: 690px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 690px;}

Thank you in advance, Kris.

Comment: remove class fixed from .progressBarContainer div and check.

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML and CSS please. If the link you posted goes dead / 404 this question will be of little use to future users with similar issues.

Comment: you defined `.form-all {
  width: 690px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 690px;
}` - too many values for one attribute

Comment: Hi Banzay, this is actually Jotform-styling, but I completely agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Absolute Position Solution:**
You said you are using `position: fixed`, but this won't inherit the width of the parent. You need to change `.progressBarContainer.fixed` to `position: absolute`, and then the form parent, `.form-all`, add `position: relative`.

This will then set the width of the progress bar to be the same as the form.

---

**Fixed Position Solution:**
There are a number of ways you can keep the progress bar sticky on the screen. You will either have to explicitly state the max-width of the progress bar in the CSS, or CSS with a JavaScript solution. The simple CSS solution would be to keep `position: fixed` assigned to `.progressBarContainer.fixed`, but then you have to specify `max-width: 690px` to `.progressBarContainer.fixed`.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I was not aware of the heritage attributes of the position-tag.

Answer (score 1):

Its position is `fixed` that's why it gets the whole screen's width when it's set to 100% width. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values) for reference

Assuming that you want the progress bar to stick to the top and since the container element `.form-all` has a `max-width` property of 690px try applying it to the progress bar element as well to prevent it from expanding to 100% of the screen width.

Otherwise simply remove the `fixed` positioning from the progress bar.

Comment: Thank you, also for the reference!